# Convenient word wrapping for long paragraphs in vim

Tags: vim, formatting, word-wrap

I am looking for a  technique of writing and editing longer paragraphs in vim.
Essentially, what i want is vim to behave like the html textarea where i am currently writing this question.

To some extent I get this behaviour if I `set wrap` and `set linebreak`, with `j` mapped to `gj` and `k` mapped to `gk`. However, when in visual mode, the movements are still line-wise and I know of no convenient way of selecting a part of a long line.

Additionally, I know that the `textwidth` option automatically breaks lines if the current column of the cursor is above a certain treshold. 
But if I edit the line from say the middle, the line doesnt break automatically when it gets too long.

I also know I can use `gq` to format a group of selected lines but it gets tiresome after a while.

What is a technique for good, automatic line wrapping in vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set `a` in your formatoptions you might get what you whant:

```
:set formatoptions+=a
```

See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#auto-format

```
...
a   Automatic formatting of paragraphs.  Every time text is inserted or
    deleted the paragraph will be reformatted.  See |auto-format|.
    When the 'c' flag is present this only happens for recognized
    comments.
...
```